# api | panic: dial tcp: lookup db-mysql: Try again

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose

I have two containers, one of my api in golang and the other of my mysql database... both go up correctly, but when the api connects to the container, I keep getting this try again error. I had adapted the code to try again and it works, but all the operations I perform give the same problem, so I suppose there is something wrong and I don't know what it could be. Can you help me?

As mentioned above, I adapted the code to keep trying until it works, but as it gives an error in all operations, it is kind of impracticable to adapt it to try until it works in all operations.

Here are my files:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: ["/app/main"]
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db-mysql
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - mysql-net
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

networks:
  mysql-net:
    driver:  bridge

volumes:
  my-db:
```

```
# Build stage
FROM golang:1.19-alpine3.16 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go build -o main cmd/server/main.go

# Run stage
FROM alpine:3.16
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
COPY .env .


EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "/app/main" ]
```

This is the part I get the error:

```
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your containers don't have any `networks:` in common.  Your application is on the Compose-provided `default` network, but the database is on a separate `mysql-net` network.  Since they're not on the same network, they can't talk to each other.

[Compose provides a network named `default` for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and for most application this works fine.  The easiest thing to do here is to delete all of the `networks:` blocks from the entire file.

Once you're doing that cleanup, there are several other things you can simplify.  There's a shorter form of `build:` if you're using the standard `Dockerfile` name; you don't need to manually specify `container_name:` or to repeat the image's `command:`; the obsolete `expose:` option does nothing and can be safely removed.  This would leave you with:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - .env  # setting MYSQL_HOST=db
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

volumes:
  my-db:
```

I note one further change here.  Both the container names and the Compose service names are usable as host names.  Normally, though, you can do almost all operations using the Compose service name, and let Compose generate the underlying container name itself.  This applies to host names for cross-container calls as well: in your `.env` file use the Compose service name `db` as a host name, rather than trying to set `container_name:` manually.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the suggestions, I changed the docker-compose and it stopped giving that error, but now it gives the connection refused ;(

Comment: A Go application can start up very quickly, but it can often take the database 30-60 seconds to become usable.  Do you also need [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)?

Comment: That's right, to work here I used the ```wait-for``` script. Thanks a lot for the help!!!